# Calculus of Weight and mass

Tags: forces, mass, weight, unit-conversion

I am confusing about some data for calculus.

First, the equivalence of weight: 1kgf=9.8N

Second, the mass of 1 Newton is: 1N/(9.8m/s$^2$).

And finally, to get the mass of 1kgf, I have to divide by the gravity.

An example of a weight of P=10N:

P=10N$\cfrac{\text{1kgf}}{9.8N}\approx1$kgf; its mass: $m=\cfrac{P}{g}=\cfrac{1kgf}{9.8m/s^2}\approx0.1kg$

While, directly from Newtons: $m=\cfrac{10N}{9.8m/s^2}\approx1kg$

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's the units.  Dividing $kgf$ by $m/s^2$ doesn't give you $kg$.

Comment: I am confused. What happened if I weight 70 kg, I must say 70kgf? I mean, to get my mass, I have to divide my weight by the gravity. What is wrong?

Comment: OK, how about if I tell you that gravity is $1 kgf / kg$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the units.  There is no such unit in the SI system as *kgf*.  kg is mass, in kilograms.  Force is Newtons.  Acceleration is m/s^2.  The three variables are tied together with Newton's 2nd Law, which is *F=ma*.

Having said that, weight is the force that gravity exerts on an object, and is defined by the equation *W=mg*, where *W* takes the place of *F*, and *g* takes the place of *a*, in Newton's 2nd Law.

Now, in case I haven't answered the question, take the units of *g*, and multiply them by *kg/kg*, which gives an answer of *g=9.8kg-m/(s^2-kg)*.  Since a Newton has units of *kg-m/s^2* (from the units of *F=ma*), this means that *g* also has units of *N/kg*.  So, from your last calculation, solving Newton's 2nd Law for mass yields *m=F/a*, which for a 1 *kg* mass yields *9.8N/(9.8N/kg)*.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found this in Wikipedia: $1 kp=1 kgf=g_n⋅(1 kg)$. So, in my problem, I must say: $m=\cfrac{P}{g_n}=\cfrac{1 kgf}{g_n}=\cfrac{1 ·g_n⋅(1 kg)}{g_n}=1 kg$